# add a play button in MWPhotoBrowser for video play

Tags: ios, uibutton, mwphotobrowser

I'm using MWPhotoBrowser in which photos and videos are shown in gridview as thumb.
and shows full size image. It works fine for image view.

I have applied code for video play in

**- (void)photoBrowser:(MWPhotoBrowser *)photoBrowser didDisplayPhotoAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index**

method to play video.In which MPMoviePlayerViewController is used to play video. It will play video directly when video image displays

I want to apply video play button to play video by user interaction. If there is any possible way to do that then please suggest. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible with the current available delegates methods, so I've made the one for my own use in my app, here you go.

**Step 1:**

Look for this file, `MWPhotoBrowser.h`

Under the delegate declarations, i.e. under this `@protocol MWPhotoBrowserDelegate <NSObject>`

add one more delegate, `- (void)photoBrowser:(MWPhotoBrowser *)photoBrowser didSelectedPhotoAtIndex:(NSUInteger)selectedPhotoIndex;` I make it optional.

Also, declare this function too, `- (void) singleTapOnCurrentPhoto;`

**Step 2:**

Now open, `MWPhotoBrowser.m` make a definition of, `- (void) singleTapOnCurrentPhoto` like this,

```
- (void) singleTapOnCurrentPhoto {
    if(self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(photoBrowser:didSelectedPhotoAtIndex:)]) {
        [self.delegate photoBrowser:self didSelectedPhotoAtIndex:self.currentIndex];
    }
}
```

**Step 3:**

Now look for this file, `MWZoomingScrollView.m`

find this method, `- (void)handleSingleTap:(CGPoint)touchPoint;`

update it like this,

```
- (void)handleSingleTap:(CGPoint)touchPoint {
    [_photoBrowser performSelector:@selector(singleTapOnCurrentPhoto)];
    [_photoBrowser performSelector:@selector(toggleControls) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.2];
}
```

**Step 4:**

You're done! You can use it in your `UIViewController` class like this,

```
- (void)photoBrowser:(MWPhotoBrowser *)photoBrowser didSelectedPhotoAtIndex:(NSUInteger)selectedPhotoIndex {
    NSLog(@"Photo tapped at index %lu",(unsigned long)selectedPhotoIndex);
}
```

**Understanding of each steps:**

- In step:1 we're declaring our own delegate method to work with `MWPhotoBrowser`, once we create we've to make use of it some where, so we've also declaring a method named `singleTapOnCurrentPhoto` to call it with the object of photo browser.
- In step:2 we've calling the delegate which we'll implement into our `UIViewController` where we're showing `MWPhotoBrowser`.
- In step:3 we'll need to know, when current photo will be tap (this was done by Michael, thanks!). So we're calling the function `singleTapOnCurrentPhoto` when user perform single tap on current photo. Here, we'll call the `singleTapOnCurrentPhoto` using the object of `_photoBrowser` of `MWPhotoBrowser`
- In step:4 we're done! Now we can use that delegate. So we're implementing into class where we need it. That's all!